# Error when connecting to PostgreSQL Database on Android Studio Java - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused

Tags: java, android, postgresql, jar

Hoping you can please assist me with the below error, I have attached the code I am using, as well as the steps I've tried to rectify it

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:342)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:253)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
    at com.accfinsoftware.skypay.Database.lambda$connect$0$com-accfinsoftware-skypay-Database(Database.java:26)
    at com.accfinsoftware.skypay.Database$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 5432) from /127.0.0.1 (port 58156) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:347)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:237)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:179)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:646)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:132)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:334)
    ... 21 more
```

I get the above on my Android Studio Java Logcat when I try to run the below code

```
public Connection connection;

private final String user = "postgres";
private final String pass = "password";
private String url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/database";

public Database()
{
    connect();

}

private void connect()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

            System.out.println("Connected");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    try
    {
        thread.join();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }
}
```

- I have added the implementation for the .jar file that I loaded in my libs folder
- My postgresql.conf file has the listen addresses set to '*'
- The ports are open for 5432
- I can connect to the databases from other systems
- My pg_hba.conf file has the below:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which postgres driver are you using? Postgres did replace the md5 method with sha in one of the latest releases; you need to double check if the driver is working with your Postgres Version

Comment: @Jelmen I have tried both postgresql-42.5.2 and postgresql-42.6.0 - I wrote some Java code on Eclipse to connect to the database and that connected perfectly fine (i used the same drivers)

Comment: are you running the code in a emulated device?

Comment: The address 127.0.0.1 (localhost) refers to the loopback interface of the device running the application. However, in the context of an Android application, 127.0.0.1 refers to the loopback interface of the Android device or emulator, not the machine running the emulator. To connect to the PostgreSQL server running on your development machine, you should use the IP address of your machine on the local network. You can find the IP address of your machine using the command ipconfig (Windows) or ifconfig (Linux/macOS). Replace 127.0.0.1 in the url variable with the correct IP address.

Comment: @Jelmen If I change the IP address to the PCs network address, I get the below

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2